# Backpropagation: why partial derivative, not full derivative?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, gradient-descent, neural-networks

After studying backpropagation for neural networks, I have a question: why can't we use full derivatives for backpropagation? I understand why partial derivatives work in backpropagation. However I wonder why we cannot (or should not) use full derivatives.

Comment: If you edit in a derivation of backpropagation you've seen, you can pinpoint the first use of partial derivatives you feel warrants a detailed explanation, but the answer will be an application of multivariable chain rules of the form$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=\sum_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial t}.$$

Answer (score 1):

It is because you ultimately want to find "in which direction" you should change the network's parameters (biases and weights), **one by one**, in order to minimize the loss.
So you look at every parameter and tweak it slightly from its value and see if the loss increases or decreases: this is equivalent to computing

$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial b^{(l)}_j} \hspace{0.5cm} or \hspace{0.5cm} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial w^{(l)}_{ij}}$$

where $(l)$ is the layer the bias or weight refers to.

To compute these quantities you use backpropagation (which is just the chain rule applied to neural networks) and this involves partial derivatives.